# No intellisense for bootstrap classes in html files on Angular - visual studio 2017

Tags: html, angular, visual-studio, intellisense

Using Angular project in Visual Studio 2017 (not VS code) how can I enable intelliSense for bootstrap classes inside the html files, I tried to add it in the `angular-cli.json` file using the unminified css:

```
"styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
      ],
```

Also tried using the `styles.css`

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
```

Not Working...

Any help is very appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Hi, please install dependencies using npm, bower, then add the css file into project, the intellisense should works, please check this doc: https://irsali.github.io/others/2017/10/06/Visual-Studio-Ensuring-Intellisense.html

Comment: Thanks, that's working!! cheers...

Comment: Hi, I'm so glad to hear that my suggestion is helpful for your issue, thank you for our confirmation.

Comment: What do you mean add it into the project?  How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While working with frameworks like Angular, we can install dependencies using npm, bower, and add the non-minified css file into project, then we can find the intellisense works as expected, please check [this doc](https://irsali.github.io/others/2017/10/06/Visual-Studio-Ensuring-Intellisense.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can install VSCode extension [IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zignd.html-css-class-completion), even though there is a small glitch in this extension. You have to type the whole tag , move to another line and come back to class name.